# Stored procedure access denied for user to database

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`vicky`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `rundaily`(IN `yesterday` DATE)
NO SQL 
begin 
    declare csession varchar(128); 
    declare clastsession varchar(128); 
    declare cactivityid int; 
    declare clastactivityid int; 
    declare cproductsk int; 
    decl
```

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'vivek'@'192.168.0.%' to database 'vivek_dev'

Comment: The DBA needs to grant you `CREATE ROUTINE` permission. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html for the list of all permissions.

Comment: This database uploaded smoothly in localhost but when I upload it on live server it is showing me this error . Can you help me ?

Comment: You probably should use the `root` user when importing the entire database.

Comment: Made the title more likely to be found in searches.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells that user `vivek` do not have proper privilege over the database `vivek_dev`.

You need to grant privileges for the user over the database to avoid this error.

Run the following code as root.

```
grant all privileges on DB Name .* to 'vivek'@'192.168.0.%' identified by "PASSWORD";
```

Change the password.
Read about [Grant Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) here

Comment: And change `localhost` to `192.168.0.%`

Comment: #1044 - Access denied for user 'vivek'@'192.168.0.%' to database 'vivek_dev'. This is the message comes

Comment: ypu need to run as root

Comment: no . Can you send me your teamviewer id so that you can do it by yourself ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont have one. You can login as root and run the above query to solve the problem